# Proof of Well-Ordering Theorem : small question

Tags: axiom-of-choice, well-orders

I am reading the proof of Well-Ordering Theorem from wikipedia and it starts as below:

"The well-ordering theorem follows from Zorn's Lemma. Take the set A of all **well-orderings** of subsets of X: an element of A is an ordered pair (a,b) where a is a subset of X and b is a well-ordering of a. A can be partially ordered by continuation"

My question is, what is the well-ordering(s) which I make is as a bold above?

I thought well-ordering is a characteristic of a set, but it expresses like a noun or well-defined conceptual noun.

Answer (score 3):

A well-ordering in this case is a particular ordering of a set that exhibits the well-ordering property. For example, the naturals are well-ordered because there exists an ordering of the set which is a well-ordering, simply the natural ordering, $1<2<3...$, but that's just one particular well-ordering. An equally valid ordering can be made by defining all of the odds less than the evens, $1<3<5<...<2<4<6...$

Comment: got it. so it denotes a certain type of ordering of element of mother set which contains the structure of well-ordering.

Comment: Yup, exactly. It is a particular ordering which exibits the well ordering property